nginx conf file is not mounted to pod
I am trying to create kubenetes on my local by using minikube.
then at first created a VM environment by using docker-compose.
then converted compose to kubenetes yml by using kompose command.
then try to use kubenetes
then I am facing error in terms of file mount.
Actually, it says this error.
kubectl apply -f .  


init: error mounting "/Users/shunsuke.h/vscode/kompose_sample/nginx/default.conf" to rootfs at "/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf": mount /Users/shunsuke.h/vscode/kompose_sample/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf (via /proc/self/fd/6), flags: 0x5000: not a directory: unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type

but this is a file.
(base) k8s ❯ cat /Users/xxxxxxxx.h/vscode/kompose_sample/nginx/default.conf
server {

    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name localhost;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        #fastcgi_keep_conn on;
        fastcgi_pass   php-fpm:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        include        fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

}

Why did it happen?
my yml file is here.
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f ../kompose_sample/compose.yml --volumes=hostPath
    kompose.service.type: LoadBalancer
    kompose.version: 1.34.0 (HEAD)
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: nginx
  name: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      io.kompose.service: nginx
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f ../kompose_sample/compose.yml --volumes=hostPath
        kompose.service.type: LoadBalancer
        kompose.version: 1.34.0 (HEAD)
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: kompose_sample/nginx:0.0.1
          name: nginx
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
              protocol: TCP
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
              name: nginx-hostpath0
      restartPolicy: Always
      volumes:
        - hostPath:
            path: /Users/shunsuke.h/vscode/kompose_sample/nginx/default.conf
            type: File
          name: nginx-hostpath0


BTW, php file can be mounted.
So I am confused.
My env is here.
Mac OS 14.7 (23H124)
minikube start --driver docker

Refer to this Stack Link and also check this Github issue which might be helpful for you.
